# Reasoning behind IUPAC nomenclature?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

> What is the reason for writing prefixes like `di` and `tri` in front of prefixes of alkyl or functional groups ?

---

[image]

---

For example in `2,3-Dimethylpentane` we write `2,3` which is the location of the methyl group in the parent chain but then we also write `Di` to indicate the presence of two methyl groups.

I do not understand why we write `Di`, isn't it obvious that if there are two locants given then there will be two methyl group ? one methyl group is not going to be present at two places simultaneously.

---

Ok now lets assume for a second that writing `Di` is somehow useful, then
in `2,2-Dimethylpentane` why we write `2,2` ? for me it is obvious that if there is `Di` before the methyl and only one locant is given then two methyl groups will be present at that location.

---

To summarise :

- In `2,3-Dimethylpentane` why we write `Di` if we have already written two locants to indicate the location of two methyl groups ?
- In `2,2-Dimethylpentane` if we write `Di` then why we write `2,2` ? I think only `2` is suffice here.

Comment: Related: [Why do we insert a numeric multiplier after group positions when naming an isomer?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/28829/7951)

Comment: @Loong I got the answer for my first question but not for the second question.

Comment: This is of course conjecture, but a point would be to make it easier to "say" the compounds. The system would be weakened if, by intuition, people called substances by different nomenclature than what they wrote. If iupac nomenclature forced us to call something methyl-methyl-pentane we would simply say dimethylpentane anyway. Might as well accomodate easy spoken names and include the prefix as well as the numerical. This way there is 1 system for all, no exceptions. Fewer exceptions means stronger system.

Comment: @StianYttervik That might explain the first part but what do you think of second part ?

Comment: I mean that it is easier for everyone if we just keep both the "oral" tradition (di-, tri-) *and* the numeric ones as the standard. If there were to be exceptions when it didn't mean anything it would be confusing and had to be decided on a case for case basis whether or not to use the numerics. Better to just always have them, they usually represent an insignificant waste of bytes...